# Python Unit test with mocking boto3 S3 resource

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, boto3, botocore

I am new to Python and have written some code in python but not a lot of unit tests, especially that involves mocking.

I would like to write unit test for this python function which uses boto3.

**simpleput.py**

```py
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def simpleput(bucket: str, filename: str):
    // s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
    s3.Object(bucket, filename).put(Body='one\ntwo')
```

I found `botocore stubber` and went onto use it: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html

Since I am using `boto3.resource` instead of `boto3.client` in my code, so based on [this suggestion](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1125#issuecomment-452468870) I wrote following test:

```py
import unittest
import boto3
from botocore.stub import Stubber
import simpleput


class TestModule(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_seed(self):
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        client = s3_resource.meta.client
        stubber = Stubber(client)
        simpleput.s3 = s3_resource // Setting this on file I want to test 

        response = {"Expiration": "whatever", "ETag": "12345", "VersionId": "1.0"}

        expected_params = {
            "Body": 'one\ntwo',
            "Bucket": 'mybucket',
            "Key": 'mykey',
        }
        stubber.add_response('put_object', response, expected_params)

        with stubber:
            service_response = client.put_object(Body='one\ntwo', Bucket='mybucket', Key='mykey')
            simpleput.simpleput('mybucket', 'mykey')

        assert service_response == response
```

Now am unable to figure out how can I use this mock/stubber to injected/intercept the call to my actual function `simpleput(bucket, filename)` that I want to test.

If I do it as shown in my code, it gives me this error:

`raise UnStubbedResponseError( botocore.exceptions.UnStubbedResponseError: Error getting response stub for operation PutObject: Unexpected API Call: A call was made but no additional calls expected. Either the API Call was not stubbed or it was called multiple times.`

Comment: I honestly fail to understand why someone voted to close this question. It's a genuine question, summarizes the issue with proper error details, has snippet of code that could be used to reproduce it. Also shows what I have tried.
And hence fulfills all the conditions that SO says needs to be met. If SO does not allow asking questions on `boto3` or `botocore` why those tags exist on SO. Pls first go ahead and vote to close those tags instead of this question.
And more importantly if you cannot help someone, at least don't pull them down.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
I only have single call to *stubber.add_response(..)* that is `stubber.add_response('put_object', response, expected_params)` which means I am expecting it only once but with my following code, I am making 2 calls and hence this error.

```py
with stubber:
    service_response = client.put_object(Body='one\ntwo', Bucket='mybucket', Key='mykey')
    simpleput.simpleput('mybucket', 'mykey')
```

So simply removing the first call (which I had added just for testing to see if the stubber is working) it worked:

```py
with stubber:
    simpleput.simpleput('mybucket', 'mykey')
```